# Ajax works only once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this form with some input fields, where upon submitting the form the data gets appended to a table, more like a list. The data gets appended to the table list and also gets sent to the data base using ajax, both action takes place when I click on submit. Below is the form.

```
<div id ="product_calculator" style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 10px; display:none;margin-top: 5px;"><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Product Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="productname" type="text" id="productname" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Width</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="width" step ="any" type="text" id="width" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>Height</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="height" step ="any" type="text" id="height" value=""><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" class="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="ADD TO LIST" />  
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is table where the data gets appended,

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
           <tbody class="details">
           </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the jquery and ajax where I append the data to the list and send it to the database as well, you can also I attach a remove button to each of my appended list item

```
$('#submit').on("click" , function(){
    var productname = $('#productname').val();
    var width = $('#width').val();
    var height = $('#height').val();
        $.ajax({
          url:"item_list_process.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{productname:productname,width:width,height:height},
          success:function(data){
              $("#list_message").html(data)
          }
      })

    var tr = '<tr>'+
               '<td><input type="text" name="product_name[]" required class="form-control product_name" value="'+productname+'"></td>'+
               '<td><input type="text" name="width[]" required class="form-control width" value="'+width+'"></td>'+
               '<td><input type="text" name="height[]" required class="form-control height" value="'+height+'"></td>'+

               '<td><input type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger remove" value="Remove"></td>'+
          '</tr>';
      $('.details').append(tr);

})
```

Now you can see I attach a remove button to each of my list item, upon clicking on the button I remove the list item from the table as well as from the data base using ajax and jquery. The code is below, I use the data from the appended list to send it to php for it to recognize which line of item to delete

```
$('.details').on('click','.remove',function(){
    var con = confirm("Do you want to remove it ?");
    if(con){
        var pro = $('.product_name').val();
        var wid = $('.width').val();
        var hei = $('.height').val();
            $.ajax({
              url:"item_list_delete.php",
              method:"POST",
              data:{pro:pro,wid:wid,hei:hei},
              success:function(data){
                  $("#delete").html(data)
              }
          })
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();     
    }
});
```

Now the problem is when I delete the data, ajax seems to be only working once when deleting the data from the data base, after that it dosent work, for example lets say I have 4 items, lets say I clicked on the 3rd item, the item gets deleted from database and also gets removed from the list, but when I click on the first item after deleting the 3rd item, the ajax dosent work anymore, nor does it work on any more of my list items when I click on thier remove button.

Comment: How are you wrapping this lines `$('.details').on('click','.remove',function(){`, `$('#submit').on("click" , function(){`? document ready or windows onload?

Comment: Have you even tried to use the Debugger?

Comment: $(document).ready()

Comment: Everything works perfectly, only the ajax part where i have to delete the items from the list, ajax seems to be working only for the first item, after that no matter how many time i click on the remove button of my other items, it only gets removed from the list ( $(this).parent().parent().remove(); this workd), but not from the data base

Comment: Try changing this `$('.details').on` to this `$('document').on`. But I think the problem is with the data got to the browser developer tools (F12). Then look in elements to see the values of the inputs. Are those the same or not ?

Comment: @Raju Are you maybe doing this part wrong? `$('.product_name').val()`? Does it select the correct product name? Try logging that in the console.

Comment: According to @Raju reply to the below answer as I thought the problem is his duplicating the same value to all the other items. So once an item get deleted other listed once become redundant.

Comment: @Sand, yes u are right, the data gets duplicated, when i send the data data of the first item by clicking on its remove button for deletion, after executing this task(which is properly deleted), when i click on another item for deletion its keeps on sending the data of the previous item i clicked on and same for every other items remove button i click on its keeps on showing  the data of the first item via $("#delete").html(data)

Comment: Can you post your `table` `HTML` after it get created using the data. The click function keep sending the dame data because all the values in the table must have been dupilicated.

Comment: @hayavuk, yes it does select the correct product name, which i checked via  $("#delete").html(data), but it only sends the first items data i click on, after which it dosent work,

Comment: @Raju, did you check that `$('.product_name').val()` is what you really want? That piece of code will select the first `.product_name` you have, not the one under the item you are trying to delete.

Comment: @Sand Well, i attached tables html code above, where the data gets appended dynamically, so in that case if you wan to see the table with the data i have upload a pic of that table

Comment: @hayavuk,Well each of my list items has one remove buttons attached to it, so when i click on any one of them it is supposed to display that particulars items product name in $('.product_name').val(); which i cheked via $("#delete").html(data); the problem is when i  click on the first items remove button it shows its proper data, and gets deleted also, but after that any list item i click on shows the data of the of the first items remove button i clicked on, indicating the ajax trigged only once, for the first item

Comment: @Raju you don't need to take a screenshot you can get the source code by just right clicking on the web page in the browser and clicking on "View source" or by pressing "F12" and getting the "Developer tools" then go to "Elements" tab the source code will be there as well. It seems like you really don't have any idea about how ti trouble shoot the code. In "Developer Tools" you will see all the data you need to trouble shoot your web app.

Comment: @Raju, I suggest you ´console.log()´ it, and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is been passed to the id='delete' via this $("#delete").html(data).
Because any data if you are manipulating via ajax thous class will not be consider for next action.

You can check weather action triggers when you click on it by adding alert('test');

for each row you can consider different id's by appending row id's to it. When you are preforming any action on remove button you can remove particular row based on the unique ids.
like

Comment: yes i did check what was being passed via $("#delete").html(data); from there i found out only the first items data is being sent, after when i click on the second item, its display the  data of the first item i clicked via $("#delete").html(data), same thing happens for all my other items, the point is only the data of my first item i click is displayed, and the same first item data is displayed when i click on my other list items after cliking the first via $("#delete").html(data)

Comment: Its easy to handle this case you can try by creating a loop like for($i=1;$i<5;$i++;){ echo "<p id='remove".$i."'><input type='button' value='remove' class='removebutton' data-id='1' data-name='testing'/><p>"; } Then in ajax you can trying $(document).on('click','.removebutton',function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');            
            var id = $(this).attr('data-name'); 
            //--- Purform Ajax action here --
   if(sucess)
    //Remove the deleted row data with the perticular id value
        });